# SQL: Find the teams containing a list users

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a game where I have teams containing a number of users. There are different amounts of users in each team but for anyone team the combination of users makes that team unique.

I have created three database tables for this.

```
 Team    User    TeamUsers
 t_id    u_id    t_id, u_id
```

If users 1, 4, 5 and 7 have been in a team together previously I would like to know the team ID of that team. What would the SQL look like for this?

I have experimented with something like this:

```
SELECT t_id FROM teamusers WHERE u_id IN (users[1], ..., users[i])
GROUP BY t_id HAVING COUNT(t_id) = users[].length;
```

`users` array is programatically filled with the values. Does this seem correct? Is there another way that's better?

Comment: How do you handle change over time? How do we know that users were member of a team *at the same time*? Does every change in members automatically create a *new* team (different `t_id`)?

Comment: Yes a change in users creates a new team. It works kind of like the SC2 teamup if you have played that game? If you play with some one that creates a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical case of **relational division**. We have assembled a whole arsenal of queries under this closely related question:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

One way to get all teams that have all given players would be what you already have. Should be among the most efficient queries.

For longer arrays, `unnest()` + `JOIN` performs better:

```
SELECT t_id
FROM  (SELECT unnest($users) AS u_id) u
JOIN   team_users USING (u_id)
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = array_length($users, 1);
```

But for just a hand full of players, it hardly matters.
For repeated use, instead of building the query in your app, you can create a table function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_teams(_users int[])
  RETURNS SETOF int AS
$func$

SELECT t_id
FROM  (SELECT unnest($1) AS u_id) u
JOIN   team_users USING (u_id)
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = array_length($1, 1);

$func$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_get_teams('{1,4,5,7}'::int[]);
```